# How to Select Specific Rows into a New Table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using SQLite 3. I have a table MyTable, as follows:

```
Create table mytable (ID as INTEGER, OrderID as INTEGER);

Insert into mytable (ID, OrderID) values (1, 1);
Insert into mytable (ID, OrderID) values (1, 2);
Insert into mytable (ID, OrderID) values (2, 1);
Insert into mytable (ID, OrderID) values (2, 3);
Insert into mytable (ID, OrderID) values (3, 1);
```

For two rows with same ID but different OrderID, like(1, 1) and (1, 2), we will call them duplicate rows.

Now I need to pick out all duplicate rows and put them into a new table called MyDupTable. For the above sample, MyDupTable should contains:

```
(1, 1);
(1, 2);
(2, 1);
(2, 3);
```

So I use the following statement:

```
Select * into MyDupTable from MyTable group by ID having Count(ID) > 1;
```

But sqlite gives an error message “near “into”, syntax error”, why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using `sub-query`, sub-query will pick all the duplicate id and then by using `in` pick rest of the columns from table and insert it in to new table

```
insert into MyDupTable 
select * from mytable where ID in(
    select ID from mytable
     group by ID
    having Count(*) > 1
    )
```

you can create table by using existing table

```
CREATE TABLE MyDupTable AS 
   select * from mytable where ID in(
        select ID from mytable
         group by ID
        having Count(*) > 1
        )
```

your query analysis

```
Select * into MyDupTable from MyTable group by ID having Count(ID) > 1;
```

1.you have used group by id but not found any selection column from MyTable , number of column used in selection must used in  group by

2. [in sql lite insert table docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)

Comment: It seems that MyDupTable must exist before invoke this statement. The statement will not create MyDupTable automatically, it will only put rows into an existing table. Is that correct?

Comment: @alancc but you can do that by using  CREATE TABLE AS SELECT expressions:

Answer (score 0):

I would use `INSERT INTO. . .` statement with `EXISTS` :

```
INSERT INTO MyDupTable (ID, orderid)
     SELECT ID, orderid
     FROM mytable mt
     WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable mt1 WHERE mt1.ID = mt.ID AND mt.orderid <> mt1.orderid);
```

Notes :

- Always qualify all columns names when you use `INSERT INTO` Statement.